# Read values from txt with rows of different sizes into a single numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, io, scipy

I need to read a file that has a structure like:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
 6 7 8 9 10
 11 22
 13 14 15 16 17
 18 19 20 21 22
 23 24
```

I need to read this file in a single array = [ 1,2,3, ... , 23, 24]

How to do that in numpy ?? Usin:

```
Array = np.genfromtxt(pathToFile, dtype=float, skip_header=1, comments='/')
```

Didn't work:

```
Line #796537 (got 2 columns instead of 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy.fromstring) instead?

```
>>> np.fromstring(''.join(open('yourfile.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()),sep=" ")


array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
        22.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
        23.,  24.])
```

> > > 

Answer (score 5):

Easier way:

```
result=np.fromfile(path_to_file,dtype=float,sep="\t",count=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need `numpy` here?

```
In [101]: with open('data1.txt') as f:
    lis=[float(y) for x in f for y in x.split()]
    print lis
   .....:     
   .....:     
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 22.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0]
```

Comment: The data here is just a example, the number are floats, and the file has 4 milion numbers, removed the ">" as they are not in the data..

Comment: if the file has floats then use `float()` instead of `int()`, I don't think using `numpy` here will have any advantage over this method.

Comment: @canesin what exactly you wanna do with those 4 million numbers, because storing those many numbers is not memory efficient.

Comment: I want to read a file that contains information about locations, but I only know the position of it in a 1D array... I believe that acessing a specific position in the file gonna be harder

Answer (score 0):

Remove new lines and save to another file:

```
open('ofile.txt','w').write(''.join(open('infile.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()))
```

Then it will work:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('ofile.txt')
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
    22.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
    23.,  24.])
```